# libGDX прорисовка объекта с сохранением

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Ребят, нужно что бы объект передвигался и оставлял за собой след

Для этого нужно делать прорисовку следующего элемента(следа) с сохранением предыдущих следов, который главный герой уже оставил

Подскажите, как это можно реализовать в libGDX?

Очень желательно пример кода.

Если нужно, моя реализация передвижения героя и класс где это все должно происходить:
level(Тут реализация передвижения свайпами)

```
package com.bellkross.ggame.gameLevels;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;

import static com.bellkross.ggame.states.MenuState.HEIGHT;
import static com.bellkross.ggame.states.MenuState.WIDTH;

public class Level {
    public static OrthographicCamera camera;

    public static final int VELOCITY = 100;
    public static final int SWIPE_LIMIT = 20;
    public static int first_x,first_y,dx,dy;
    public static float ggHeight, ggWidth;

    public static  Texture gg,lineGG;//glavniy geroy
    public static Texture standart_background;
    public static Texture[] levelBackgrounds;

    public static  Rectangle mh;//main hero

    public static InputProcessor LEVEL_INPUT_PROCESSOR;

    public Level(){
    levelBackgrounds = new Texture[10];
    levelBackgrounds[0]= new Texture("lvl1B.png");

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    standart_background = new Texture("gameBackground.png");

    gg = new Texture("gg30.png");
    lineGG = new Texture("line.png");
    ggHeight = gg.getHeight();
    ggWidth = gg.getWidth();
    mh   = new Rectangle(0, HEIGHT - ggHeight, ggWidth, ggHeight);

    LEVEL_INPUT_PROCESSOR = new InputProcessor() {
        /*touchDown():метод вызывается, когда палец коснулся экрана или была нажата кнопка мыши.
            * Сообщает последние     известные координаты.*/
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {
            first_x = x;
            first_y = y;
            return true;
        }
        /*touchDragged(): метод вызывается, когда палец перемещается по экрану
         * или перемещается мышь с нажатой кнопкой.*/
        @Override
        public boolean touchDragged(int second_x, int second_y, int pointer) {
            dx = second_x - first_x;
            dy = second_y - first_y;
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean mouseMoved(int x, int y) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean touchUp(int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {
            return false;
        }
        };
    }


    /**Реализация движения гг
     * @param mh квадрат гг
     * @param dx
     * @param dy*/
    public static void handleInput(Rectangle mh,int dx, int dy){
        if(dx>0){
            if(dx>Math.abs(dy))
                Level.moveRight(mh,dx);//move right
            if(dy>=0) {
                if (Math.abs(dx) < dy)
                    Level.moveUp(mh,dy);//move up
            }else
            if(Math.abs(dx)<Math.abs(dy))
                Level.moveDown(mh,dy);//move down
        }else{
            if(dx==0)
                if(dy>0)
                    Level.moveUp(mh,dy);//move up
                else
                    Level.moveDown(mh,dy);//move down

            if(dx<0){
                if(Math.abs(dx)>Math.abs(dy))
                    Level.moveLeft(mh,dx);//move left
                if(dy>=0){
                    if(Math.abs(dx)<Math.abs(dy))
                        Level.moveUp(mh,dy);//move up
                }else
                if(Math.abs(dx)<Math.abs(dy))
                    Level.moveDown(mh,dy);//move down
            }
        }
    }

    public static void moveUp(Rectangle mh, int dy){
        if(Math.abs(dy)>=SWIPE_LIMIT&&mh.y>0)
            mh.y -= VELOCITY * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    }

    public static void moveDown(Rectangle mh, int dy){
        if(Math.abs(dy)>=SWIPE_LIMIT&&mh.y<HEIGHT-mh.getHeight())
            mh.y += VELOCITY * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    }

    public static void moveRight(Rectangle mh, int dx){
        if(Math.abs(dx)>=SWIPE_LIMIT&&mh.x<WIDTH-mh.getWidth())
            mh.x += VELOCITY * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    }

    public static void moveLeft(Rectangle mh, int dx){
        if(Math.abs(dx)>=SWIPE_LIMIT&&mh.x>0)
            mh.x -= VELOCITY * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    }
}
```

Level_1(Тут объект передвигается и должен оставлять линию за собой)

```
package com.bellkross.ggame.gameLevels;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.bellkross.ggame.states.GameStateManager;
import com.bellkross.ggame.states.State;

import static com.bellkross.ggame.gameLevels.Level.lineGG;
import static com.bellkross.ggame.gameLevels.Level.standart_background;
import static com.bellkross.ggame.gameLevels.Level.dx;
import static com.bellkross.ggame.gameLevels.Level.dy;
import static com.bellkross.ggame.gameLevels.Level.gg;
import static com.bellkross.ggame.gameLevels.Level.LEVEL_INPUT_PROCESSOR;
import static com.bellkross.ggame.gameLevels.Level.mh;
import static com.bellkross.ggame.gameLevels.Level.levelBackgrounds;
import static com.bellkross.ggame.states.MenuState.HEIGHT;
import static com.bellkross.ggame.states.MenuState.WIDTH;


public class Level_1 extends State{

    private Texture e1;
    private Rectangle e1_r;
    private float e1Height, e1Width;
    private Level level;



    public Level_1(GameStateManager gsm) {
        super(gsm);
        level = new Level();

        e1 = new Texture("gg30.png");
        e1Height = e1.getHeight();
        e1Width = e1.getWidth();

        e1_r = new Rectangle(WIDTH/2 - e1Width/2,
                HEIGHT/2-e1Height/2,e1Width,e1Height);

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(LEVEL_INPUT_PROCESSOR);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(float dt) {
        Level.handleInput(mh,dx,dy);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
        sb.setProjectionMatrix(Level.camera.combined);
        sb.begin();
        sb.draw(levelBackgrounds[0], 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        sb.draw(standart_background, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        sb.draw(gg, mh.x, mh.y);
        sb.draw(e1,e1_r.x,e1_r.y);
        sb.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        levelBackgrounds[0].dispose();
        standart_background.dispose();
        gg.dispose();
        e1.dispose();
        lineGG.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    protected void handleInput() {}
}
```